# How to use independent xVals for a multiDataSet scatterChart

Tags: scatter-plot, ios-charts

FYI, I would use iOS-charts (Swift version in OSX) to display several discrete cumulative probability curves in one chart. 
  The way I understand iOS-charts is that every chart has one xVals array that is shared between the chart's different dataSets (curves). 
  However, the random occurrences (x-values) for each sampled distribution have nothing to do with x-values in other curves. 
  Is there an easy way (or what method do I need to override) to provide an xVals array for each dataSet? 
*BTW, thanks for making this compatible with OSX as well.*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: Currently no. I you have to figure out on your own.